# Google Play Services causing WindowManagerService error

Tags: android, window, google-plus

Basically I am trying to use Google Play Service 5.0.77 in my app.  Sign-in appears to work properly but then there is a problem with the Window in logcat.  Any recommendations?

Device Nexus 5
Android 4.4.4
Android Studio: 0.8.1

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 20140705
        versionName "1.14.0705"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}
```

Logcat File

```
W/WindowManager( 1675): java.lang.RuntimeException: here
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.rebuildAppWindowListLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8027)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.rebuildAppWindowListLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7963)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.handleAnimatingStoppedAndTransitionLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8707)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner(WindowManagerService.java:9221)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedLoop(WindowManagerService.java:8179)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8121)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.access$300(WindowManagerService.java:157)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:7155)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/WindowManager( 1675):         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/WindowManager( 1675): This window was lost: Window{44226800 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity}
W/WindowManager( 1675): mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{44650b90 16380:u0a10007} mClient=android.os.BinderProxy@4421c070
W/WindowManager( 1675): mOwnerUid=10007 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.google.android.gms appop=NONE
W/WindowManager( 1675): mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=1 fl=#1810102 pfl=0x8 fmt=-2 wanim=0x1030002}
W/WindowManager( 1675): Requested w=1080 h=1776 mLayoutSeq=29764
W/WindowManager( 1675): mBaseLayer=21000 mSubLayer=0 mAnimLayer=21045+1000=21045 mLastLayer=22045
W/WindowManager( 1675): mToken=AppWindowToken{454d79c8 token=Token{44bbb560 ActivityRecord{451e4880 u0 com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity t264}}}
W/WindowManager( 1675): mRootToken=AppWindowToken{454d79c8 token=Token{44bbb560 ActivityRecord{451e4880 u0 com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity t264}}}
W/WindowManager( 1675): mAppToken=AppWindowToken{454d79c8 token=Token{44bbb560 ActivityRecord{451e4880 u0 com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity t264}}}
W/WindowManager( 1675): mViewVisibility=0x8 mHaveFrame=true mObscured=false
W/WindowManager( 1675): mSeq=0 mSystemUiVisibility=0x0
W/WindowManager( 1675): mGivenContentInsets=[0,0][0,0] mGivenVisibleInsets=[0,0][0,0]
W/WindowManager( 1675): mConfiguration={1.15 310mcc410mnc en_US ldltr sw360dp w360dp h567dp 480dpi nrml port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
W/WindowManager( 1675): mHasSurface=true mShownFrame=[76.4776,125.76312][1156.4775,1901.7632] isReadyForDisplay()=false
W/WindowManager( 1675): mFrame=[0,0][1080,1776] last=[0,0][1080,1776]
W/WindowManager( 1675): mSystemDecorRect=[0,75][1080,1776] last=[0,75][1080,1776]
W/WindowManager( 1675): Frames: containing=[0,0][1080,1776] parent=[0,0][1080,1776]
W/WindowManager( 1675):     display=[0,0][1080,1776] overscan=[0,0][1080,1920]
W/WindowManager( 1675):     content=[0,75][1080,1776] visible=[0,75][1080,1776]
W/WindowManager( 1675):     decor=[0,75][1080,1776]
W/WindowManager( 1675): Cur insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,75][0,0] visible=[0,75][0,0]
W/WindowManager( 1675): Lst insets: overscan=[0,0][0,0] content=[0,75][0,0] visible=[0,75][0,0]
W/WindowManager( 1675): WindowStateAnimator{4437a930 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity}:
W/WindowManager( 1675):   mSurface=Surface(name=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity)
W/WindowManager( 1675):   mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN mLastHidden=true
W/WindowManager( 1675):   Surface: shown=false layer=22045 alpha=0.0 rect=(76.4776,125.76312) 1080.0 x 1776.0
W/WindowManager( 1675):   mShownAlpha=0.291874 mAlpha=1.0 mLastAlpha=0.0
W/WindowManager( 1675):   mGlobalScale=1.0 mDsDx=0.85837483 mDtDx=0.0 mDsDy=0.0 mDtDy=0.85837483
W/WindowManager( 1675): mExiting=false mRemoveOnExit=false mDestroying=true mRemoved=false
W/WindowManager( 1675): Current app token list:
V/WindowManager( 1675):   Display 0
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #13: Token{42e09a28 ActivityRecord{4369a7f8 u0 txt2lrn.com.analyticstest/.LandingActivity t264}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #12: Token{44b3cfb0 ActivityRecord{43e19ea0 u0 com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity t202}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #11: Token{44a53b50 ActivityRecord{42e67648 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL t95}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #10: Token{44659f70 ActivityRecord{436710d8 u0 com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.activity.conversationlist.ConversationListActivity t260}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #9: Token{4450aa88 ActivityRecord{42e886b0 u0 com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.SplashActivity t260}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #8: Token{43d0ed68 ActivityRecord{42df93e8 u0 com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail t259}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #7: Token{438e6e28 ActivityRecord{4367b988 u0 com.txt2lrn.www/.LandingActivity t191}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #6: Token{435689f8 ActivityRecord{43b4bd10 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.companion.StatusActivity t212}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #5: Token{43a2b768 ActivityRecord{4386a338 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.companion.StatusActivity t212}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #4: Token{43bef600 ActivityRecord{43aba5a0 u0 com.google.android.dialer/.extensions.GoogleDialtactsActivity t164}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #3: Token{43f60278 ActivityRecord{42df7800 u0 com.google.android.dialer/com.android.dialer.calllog.CallLogActivity t164}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #2: Token{42e29828 ActivityRecord{43810dc8 u0 com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets/com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.trix.TrixActivity t201}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #1: Token{4395e318 ActivityRecord{437f7450 u0 com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets/com.google.android.apps.docs.app.DocumentOpenerActivityDelegate t201}}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #0: Token{442aca08 ActivityRecord{435b5818 u0 com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets/com.google.android.apps.docs.app.DocListActivity t201}}
W/WindowManager( 1675): Final window list:
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #0: Window{443d0f48 u0 SearchPanel}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #1: Window{438eb220 u0 NavigationBar}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #2: Window{437e4328 u0 StatusBar}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #3: Window{436eb7d0 u0 Keyguard}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #4: Window{438cd1c0 u0 KeyguardScrim}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #5: Window{43bfdb28 u0 InputMethod}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #6: Window{43c28fc0 u0 txt2lrn.com.analyticstest/txt2lrn.com.analyticstest.LandingActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #7: Window{43c9e5b0 u0 com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #8: Window{4328f548 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #9: Window{440b24c0 u0 com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/com.google.android.apps.googlevoice.activity.conversationlist.ConversationListActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #10: Window{4409a6e8 u0 com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/com.google.android.apps.googlevoice.SplashActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #11: Window{43ce9df0 u0 com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #12: Window{43b78078 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.companion.StatusActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #13: Window{437952b0 u0 com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.companion.StatusActivity}
V/WindowManager( 1675):   #14: Window{43b73a70 u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

use the normal one